# What computer case do these 3.5" drive trays go to?

Tags: computer-building, case

I have some leftover drive trays in my parts bin and I can't figure out which case they belong to. Does anyone recognize them?

Please note that I am looking for an exact match. It's impossible to compare based on only vague similarity due to the differences in case-specific tolerances. For example, these look similar to the sleds used in the Antec Sonata are too deep and won't lock into place. They are also similar to the sleds used in the Rosewill THOR 2 and will lock into place but are loose compared to the original case selds.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any markings on the sides?

Comment: No markings on any side.

Comment: Many generic and name brand cases use that style

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What computer case do these 5.25" drive bay covers go to?](https://superuser.com/questions/1592570/what-computer-case-do-these-5-25-drive-bay-covers-go-to)

Comment: No. That's a completely different question...

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess they'd fit in many older Dell models. I am sure some custom computer cases also fit them

--EDIT:
Seems it may be a Lian Li case:
https://news.softpedia.com/news/New-Full-Tower-Case-from-Lian-Li-Has-HDD-Bays-Behind-the-Motherboard-Tray-452979.shtml
https://www.techpowerup.com/review/lian-li-pc-o11-dynamic/5.html